# How to search for an item, return it's Id and update that record in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to make a simple html/js app that can add and update records in a table hosted by Azure mobile services.

However I have struck a bit of a problem and I am struggling to understand the documentation. I know how to create a record:

```
var item = { event_name: event.getName(), event_time: event.getTime(), event_date: event.getDate(), event_description: event.getDescription() };

client.getTable("event").insert(item);
```

However I am not sure how to update a record once it is already created. The following code:

```
client.getTable("event").update(item);
```

requires that the item has an id, which is then used to match it in the table. Unfortunately I am struggling to get a record's Id from the table. I assume I need to do something like:

```
client.getTable("event").where({event_name: myEventName});
```

But I don't know how to implement this or use the data it returns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a continuation to retrieve the value of the read call. At that point, you'll have the id of the item you want to update. Something along the lines of

```
var table = client.getTable('event');
table.where({ event_name: myEventName }).read().then(
    function(results) {
        if (results.length) {
            var item = results[0];
            item.event_description = 'your updated description';
            table.update(item).then(
                function(updated) {
                    alert('The item was updated');
                });
        }
    });
```

The doc at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/ has more information on how to use the Azure Mobile Services client library for HTML/JS.